# Merging or combining multiple *.XYZ data into one *.XYZ form using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

[image]

I have multiple ".xyz" format coordinate files (50 files), I want to merge or combine all these 50 files into one ".xyz" format file. Above image shows how my date look like.

Is there any plug-in available in QGIS?

I have tried "**r.out.xyz**" command in QGIS GRASS, but it is not combining my multiple dataset,  I have jut got an empty file as an output.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the code below and insert it in the Python console within QGIS:
Replace the path `C:\Users\Username` with  your path the .xyz files are stored

```
import os
import pandas as pd

#enter path with .xyz files here --> # replace C:\Users\Username with the path where all files are stored
path = r'C:\Users\Username\\'

x = [a for a in os.listdir(path) if a.endswith(".xyz")]

for i in x:
    df = pd.read_csv(path + i, sep=' ', error_bad_lines=False)
    df_new = df.append(df, ignore_index=True)

#new file is written to same directory
df_new.to_csv(path + 'dgm_merged.xyz', sep=' ')
```

Comment: are you sure every file has same columns?

Comment: yes, i have checked it

Comment: run line by line and tell when the error occurs.
Have you tried using another script platform such as Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda distribution?

Comment: I did try to run in in Python IDEL, but it is not working either. I think the script is not importing pandas as pd

Comment: than you might install pandas before...whats the error like?

Comment: File "C:\Users\Maiyourathaan.Karuna\Downloads\dgm1_meta\rrr\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129842/discussion-between-maiyourathaan-and-jonas-apelt).

Comment: I changed my code one more time and added an argument in pd.read_csv()
might work...

Comment: For me the code works but the merged file is no longer readable by QGIS (Version 3.24). Do xyz-files need the coordinates in the filename like HGT ones do?